# Mocking CKContainer for Unit Testing

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, ios8, cloudkit

I am using CloudKit in my application and am trying to mock CKContainer to test my Managers. Here is what i tried:

```
    func testAccountStatus() {

class MockCloudContainer: CKContainer {

  override func accountStatusWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((CKAccountStatus, NSError!) -> Void)!)
  {
    completionHandler(CKAccountStatus.NoAccount, NSError())
  }
}

let loginManager = LoginManager.sharedInstance
let expectation = expectationWithDescription("iCloudStatus")

var isTestFinished = false
loginManager.iCloudStatusWithCompletionHandler { (status, error) -> Void in

  if (isTestFinished) {
    return
  }

  expectation.fulfill()
  XCTAssertTrue(status.isEqualToString("NoAccount"), "Status is Available")

}

waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, { error in
  isTestFinished = true
  XCTAssertNil(error, "Error")
})
```

But i am getting error while compiling the code

> :0: error: cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable

What is best way I am using mock object to test my LoginManager class ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to mock the CKContainer. The only solution would be to create a thin data access layer between your app and the CloudKit code and then mock that layer. But still you would not be able to unit test that thin layer itself.

Comment: Thanks Edwin, I actually created a wrapper class connecting to CloudKit and then mocking the wrapper. It works as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea for this problem. But I'm not good at swift so I provide my code in `Objective-C`
Firstly , try create `CKContainerMock` in your testClass like this:

```
@interface CKContainerMock : CKContainer
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^mCompletionHandlerMock)(CKAccountStatus accountStatus,NSError *error);
- (void)accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(CKAccountStatus accountStatus, NSError *error))completionHandler
@end

@implementation CKContainerMock
- (void)accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(CKAccountStatus accountStatus, NSError *error))completionHandler {
  self.mCompletionHandlerMock = completionHandler;
}
@end
```

In your testFunction 
**Example:**
Success case:

```
 -(void) testCKContainerResultSucces {
       LoginManager loginManager = [LoginManager sharedInstance];
       CKContainerMock *ckContainerMock = [[CKContainerMock alloc] init];
       [loginManager setCKContainer:ckContainerMock]; // Change your ckContainer object to mockObject.
       [loginManager iCloudStatusWithCompletionHandler:^(CKAccountStatus accountStatus,NSError *error) {
          XCAssert(accountStatus == CKAccountStatusAvailable);
        }];
       loginManager.ckContainer.mCompletionHandlerMock(CKAccountStatusAvailable,nil);
    }
```

Error case:

```
-(void) testCKContainerResultError {
   LoginManager loginManager = [LoginManager sharedInstance];
   CKContainerMock *ckContainerMock = [[CKContainerMock alloc] init];
   [loginManager setCKContainer:ckContainerMock]; //Change your ckContainer object to mockObject.
   [loginManager iCloudStatusWithCompletionHandler:^(CKAccountStatus accountStatus,NSError *error) {
      XCAssertNotNil(error);
    }];
   loginManager.ckContainer.mCompletionHandlerMock(nil,[NSError errorWithDomain:NSPOSIXErrorDomain code:22 userInfo:nil]);
}
```

[Greate mock example for you](https://github.com/salabaha/TestNetworking/blob/master/TestNetworkingTests/MockAFNetworkingGET.h)

Hope this help.

Comment: Hello Hu, this is exactly what i ended up doing. I created a wrapper class connecting to CloudKit and then mocking the wrapper. The wrapper is kind of dummy class which talks to CloudKit and sends back the response thats it. So in that case we dont need to test the wrapper. It works as accepted. Thanks for the detailed explanation and example link.